# color '.py' files in MAC terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am working in a directory that has a lot of files. I was wondering whether there is a way to color all the `.py` using the same color. Also, in that same directory I am running simulations that have a lot of output text files but I am only interested in the one called `fort.1`. Is there a way to color code this file too?

I am using the HOMEBREW mac terminal and here is the code I wrote in the `.profile`

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced # for dark terminal themes

# Tell grep to highlight matches
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

Answer (score 1):

[OSX ls](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) ([BSD ls](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls&sektion=1)) doesn't support coloring files based on their *names*, but only on their *types* (file, directory, socket, etc).

To do what you want, you would need a different tool.  While you *could* install [GNU coreutils with HomeBrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities), that has drawbacks too (causing unexpected behavior).